# boost::variant get last accessed type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

This is what I want to do:

```
boost::variant a<int, string>;
int b;
a=4;
b=a; //doesn't work. What is the easiest way to make b=4?
```

I know I can use get, but I want to be able to do this without specifying the type. I can do it with apply_visitor and a visitor object, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a compiler that supports C++0x, you can use the amazing `decltype`:

```
boost::variant a<int, string>;
int b;
a = 4;
b = boost::get<decltype(b)>(a);
```

I don't know why you'd want to do this though since you already know the type.

Comment: Note that this will throw if `a` doesn't have the same type as `b`. So it is very fragile code; that's why you generally want to use visitors for dealing with `variant`s.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a helper function:

```
template <class V, typename T>
copy_variant(const V& v, T& t) { t = get<T>(v); }

// ...

copy_variant(a, b);
```

But seriously, I think this costs you more than it buys you.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

You can call `variant<>::which()` to get the index of the `variant<>`'s currently initialized type or `variant<>::type()` to get the `std::type_info` for the currently initialized type, but there's no way to extract the *value* of the currently initialized type other than `get<>` and `apply_visitor`.